# MapReduce - Reducer giving wrong output date

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a MapReduce program to parse the values from CSV.

The data set is as follows -

PRAVEEN,40020,Baby,026A2,12/04/2015

PRAVEEN,40020,TOY,0383,1/04/2014

PRAVEEN,2727272,BOOK,03383,03/14/2013

PRAVEEN,22636,BIKE,7373737,12/24/2012

My Map function is reading the first value(ie UserName) from CSV as KEY and last value ie Date as VALUE

My Reduce function is also very simple , I have to select the latest date as the VALUE from the list of VALUES for a particular KEY ie UserName

The code is as Follows -

```
  package com.test.mapreduce;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.text.ParseException;
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Date;
  import java.util.HashSet;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Set;

  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
  import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
  import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;





 public class RetailCustomerAnalysis_2 extends Configured implements Tool {
             public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
             implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

      private Text key1 = new Text();
      private Text value1 = new Text();
      private int noofFields = 5;



 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                 OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                 Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        String line = value.toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");
        String[] split = line.split(",");


        if(split.length!=noofFields){
        return;
        }

        else {
            key1.set(split[0].toString().trim()); 
            value1.set(split[4].toString().trim());
            System.out.println(split[4].toString().trim());
            output.collect(key1, value1);
     }
    }
  }

 public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase
 implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

 public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,
                    OutputCollector<Text, Text> output,
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
     Date date = new Date();

     List<Text> dateList = new ArrayList<Text>();

     for(Iterator<Text> it = values; it.hasNext();) {
         // add the values in the arrayList
         dateList.add((Text) it.next());
     }


     if(dateList.size()==1){ //If the mapper output has only one date , then select that date 
                             // as the VALUE
     try  {
            date = formatter.parse(dateList.get(0).toString());
          } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     } //If part ends 

     else {
             try {
               date = formatter.parse(dateList.get(0).toString()); 
                      //select the first date from list
             } catch (ParseException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
             }

             for(int i=0 ; i <dateList.size();++i){
                   try {
                   //compare the selected date with the rest of the dates in the list.
                   if((formatter.parse(dateList.get(i).toString())).compareTo(date)>0){
                       date=formatter.parse(dateList.get(i).toString());
                       // getting the max date from the list
                        }
                   }
                   catch (ParseException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
             } //for loops ends
     }  // else part ends    

     Text value = new Text(date.toString());
       output.collect(key, value);
      }
  }



 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Configuration conf = getConf();

 JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, RetailCustomerAnalysis_2.class);

 Path in = new Path(args[0]);
 Path out = new Path(args[1]);
 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

 job.setJobName("RetailCustomerAnalysis_2");
 job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
 job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

 job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
 job.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");

 JobClient.runJob(job);
 return 0;
  }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
 int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new RetailCustomerAnalysis_2(), args);

 System.exit(res);
 }

 }
```

But I'm getting random date from the list as result. Can Anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is mostly correct. The reducer implementation has to be modified slightly. The below code snipper creating the problem

```
for(Iterator<Text> it = values; it.hasNext();) {
   // add the values in the arrayList
   dateList.add((Text) it.next());
}
```

In the above code snippet same value object is used in each itreation, only their contents are being changed.

For example, Assume Mapreduce run with following input

PRAVEEN,4002013454,Baby,026A12,12/04/2015

PRAVEEN,4002013454,TOY,020383,1/04/2014

PRAVEEN,2727272727272,BOOK,03383,03/14/2013

PRAVEEN,2263637373,BIKE,7373737,12/24/2012

In the reduce method 'dateList' object elemets has values (12/24/2012, 12/24/2012, 12/24/2012, 12/24/2012) after the for loop completion on the values. This leads to incorrect execution of the remaining code and final output is wrong.

Instead you change code as below

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        //-----Modified section START-----------
        List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(Iterator<Text> it = values; it.hasNext();) {
            // add the values in the arrayList
            dateList.add(((Text)it.next()).toString());
        }
        //----Modified section END--------------
        if(dateList.size()==1){ //If the mapper output has only one date , then select that date 
            // as the VALUE
            try  {
                date = formatter.parse(dateList.get(0).toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } //If part ends 
        else {
            String str = dateList.get(0).toString();
            try {

                date = formatter.parse(dateList.get(0).toString());
                //select the first date from list
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i=0 ; i <dateList.size();++i){
                try {
                    //compare the selected date with the rest of the dates in the list.
                    if((formatter.parse(dateList.get(i).toString())).compareTo(date)>0){
                        date=formatter.parse(dateList.get(i).toString());
                        // getting the max date from the list
                    }
                }
                catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } //for loops ends
        }  // else part ends    

        Text value = new Text(date.toString());
        output.collect(key, value);
    }
}
```

Please refer [Hadoop Reducer Values in Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024638/hadoop-reducer-values-in-memory) for more details about object reference in map,reduce methods.

Comment: Hi thanks a ton, it solved my problem, but still dint understand how it worked as u hardly changed the code in the buggy snippet

Comment: @Rahul, The issue is with object reference. In the code while adding 'Text' object to dateList, all the Text objects are referring to single memory location in the heap. (This is because the MapReduce framework reuses the object and only changes the state). During the last itreation the Text object value is set to 12/24/2012. This means all the elements in dateList has values as 12/24/2012.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :) But with the buggy snippet I was getting the first value from the list as the "result" date.