# Why Iterable is not obligated to return new iterator each time iterator() method is called?

Tags: java, hadoop, iterator

Few days ago I had a struggle with a strange bug, that occurred in my map reduce task.

Finally, it turned out that hadoop `ValueIterable` class that implements `Iterable` interface creates a single instance of iterator and returns it on every call of `iterator()` method.

```
protected class ValueIterable implements Iterable<VALUEIN> {
  private ValueIterator iterator = new ValueIterator();
  @Override
  public Iterator<VALUEIN> iterator() {
    return iterator;
  } 
}
```

That means if you iterate over `ValueIterable` once, you are not able to iterate it again.

I decided to check [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator()) and seems that it does not require `Iterable` to return different iterators every time (or just missing the requirement?). Diving deeper I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/839195/2513573) answer telling that having a single iterator violates `Iterator` contract, since it can not traverse the collection more than once.

1. Who is correct here? Should Iterable return new iterators? Why are java docs unclear?
2. What would be the correct way for this hadoop class to tell client that traverse is impossible? I mean if it will throw `IllegalStateException`, would it violate `Iterator#hasNext()` method contract?

Comment: ValueIterator has reset method. What does it do? May be it's that you need.

Comment: @DenisGavrus maybe it does, but in client map reduce code there is only Iterable interface, and it is not a good idea to cast this Iterable to inner hadoop class. And the question is more about specification, this hadoop class is just a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6141375/823393):

> The Iterator you receive from that Iterable's iterator() method is special. The values may not all be in memory; Hadoop may be streaming them from disk. They aren't really backed by a Collection, so it's nontrivial to allow multiple iterations.

There is no actual defined contract that states that each `Iterator` returned by `Iterable.iterator()` should repeat the same sequence. This is only a custom because it is expected behaviour.

Hadoop - or any other library - is therefore *allowed* to break the rules on this.

The java docs are unclear for exactly this purpose - to let the implementors of `Iterable` have the wiggle room to do it any way they want.

How you should do it - like the other answers mentioned in the link - retain a list of already iterated items for a later repeat iteration - but be warned, this may be a **huge** collection in a live hadoop environment so you may well break.

Comment: The real problem is not about fixing this particular issue - I've already done that. I am worried because there were no signals for me, that iteration is not possible and I just got unexpected behavior. And I'd like to know who is guilty here and how it could be fixed.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker - I'd say the mistake was made by the hadoop documentation or yourself for not reading it. i.e. Either the docs are unclear or you didn't read them carefully enough.