# How to use the hasNext() and hasPrevious() method for the `smart-list` Linked List module for Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, linked-list

I am using [singly-linked-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/singly-linked-list) to manage my in-out transactions but singly-linked-list is not provided hasPrevious() method.

Why I need hasPrevious() method ?

In some conditions I want to iterate linked list twice in same method signature [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111248/iterate-twice-on-values)

So I moved to [smart-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smart-list) which is provided hasPrevious() but I could not make this work. [See example](https://tonicdev.com/56ebff0884ccdd11001ebed0/56ed0f071a456f1100df1938)

Can anyone please suggest me how to use hasNext() and hasPrevious() in smart-list or any other solution?

Comment: Could you share what you've attempted so far? It's a little difficult to provide help without some code.

Comment: @gnerkus I have provided example tried using smart-list

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](https://bitbucket.org/atanasplachkov/smart-list/src/ebd22c29868c03dab81529dd0667177c370d08b8/lib/list.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) of the `list` for the `smart-list` module, the iterators are present in the `_first` and `_last` properties of the list:

```
var List = require("smart-list")
var templist = new List()

templist.push("foo");

templist._first.hasNext(); // false
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but how to get value "foo" in variable

Comment: The `data` property contains the value. So `console.log(a.data);`.

Comment: [see this example](https://tonicdev.com/56ebff0884ccdd11001ebed0/56eced7384ccdd11001eeefd) what if I want to take sum of all elements present in linked list

Comment: `templist._first` contains the first element ('101').

Comment: Yes I got it but how can I traverse through list till nth record. It only traverse up to number of times I have written next()